# matplotlib figure in GTK with tools

Tags: python, matplotlib, pygtk, figure

When I create a figure in matplotlib I get these nice tools to move the graph around zoom in and out ect. However the only way I know how to put the figure into a GTK GUI is by converting it to a drawing area. When I convert I obviously lose the nice tools.

Is there a better way of putting a matplotlib figure into a GTK GUI so I can keep the tools?

[image: with tools]

[image: without tools]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example, hope it helps:

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure as F
from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtkagg import FigureCanvasGTKAgg as FC
from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtkagg import NavigationToolbar2GTKAgg as NT

import gtk

fig = F()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(range(10),range(10))

main = gtk.Window()
main.set_default_size(800,600)
main.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
box = gtk.VBox()
main.add(box)

fc = FC(fig)
box.pack_start(fc)
nt = NT(fc, main)
box.pack_start(nt, expand=False, fill=False)
main.show_all()
gtk.main()
```